# PHP warning - Use of undefined constant ‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’ ‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’ on wp-config.php

Tags: php, admin, login, ssl, warnings

I have a bothering PHP warning for ages, and I am wondering if someone has solution to this.
The following two-line warning is constantly recording in my error_log file:

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’ - assumed '‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/myuser/public_html/wp-config.php on line 92

PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant ‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’ - assumed '‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/myuser/public_html/wp-config.php on line 93
```

In wp-config.php I have the following for line 92 and 93 lines:

```
define(‘FORCE_SSL_LOGIN’, true);
define(‘FORCE_SSL_ADMIN’, true);
```

line 91 is empty
and line 90 is `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

More information:
My php version: 7.4.16;
Webserver: LiteSpeed;
cURL Version: 7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1k.

I have this warning more than a year or two years and with different versions of phps

I am using the plug-in Really Simple SSL on my website as well and everything is fine with that.
I also use All-in-one security and firewall on my websites.

Deactivating of plug-ins didn’t help.
Any solution to this?

Comment: It's the quote.. Use `'` instead of `‘`

Comment: Oh! Thanks a million! 
Now it is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Edit wp-config file :

```php
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

just copy this and paste in wp-config file.

best wishes for you

Answer (score 0):

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://RanaAJANS.com/' ); #httpS...
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://RanaAJANS.com/' ); #httpS...
define( 'FORCE_SSL', true); 
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.RanaAJANS.com');
@ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', true);
@ini_set( 'session.cookie_secure', true);
@ini_set( 'session.use_only_cookies', true);
#header( 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
```